# Collect a total of 20 dollars from $4$ children and $3$ adults,if each child can contribute up to $6$ dollars,each adult can give up to $10$ dollars.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In how many ways can I collect a total of $20$ dollars from $4$ different children and $3$ different adults, if each child can contribute up to $6$ dollars, each adult can give up to $10$ dollars, and each individual gives a nonnegative whole number of dollars?

---

How should I start? Generating functions? Counting?

Comment: Sounds like finding term $x^{20}$ coefficient in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^6)^4\cdot (1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{10})^3$.

Comment: And just for fun we can "mark" the number of donors who contributed the "limit" (as Joffan has based his counting argument on). with the bivariate g.f.: nn = 20; CoefficientList[
  Series[(y x^6 + (1 - x^6)/(1 - x))^4*(y x^10 + (1 - x^10)/(1 - 
          x))^3, {x, 0, nn}], {x, y}] // Grid

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely generating functions have a tidy solution. Otherwise you have to use a bit of inclusion-exclusion:

$$\begin{align}
{26 \choose 6} - 4{19 \choose 6} &- 3{15 \choose 6} + {4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 6} + 4\cdot 3 {8 \choose 6} \\[1em]
&= 230230-108528-15015+5544+336 \\ &= 112567
\end{align}$$

representing options without limits, less options where one child or one adult breaks their limit, adding back 2 children or an adult/child combination  breaking their limits. You can't get three donors breaking their limit simultaneously.